# Analytic function with something Cauchy

Tags: complex-analysis

> Suppose that $f$ is analytic in the punctured disc $0<|z|<2$ and that $|f(z)|\leq M$ for each $z$ in the same punctured disc. Let $\Gamma$ be the unit circle $C(0:1)$. Prove that $\int_\Gamma f(z)\;\mathrm{d}z=0$.

So I am assuming that you need to use the Cauchy Integral formula but I am not sure how to exactly how this. Do I use that the Cauchy Riemann equations to show that it is zero?

Comment: Since $f$ is bounded in a neighborhood of the origin, this means you can extend $f$ to all of the disk.

Answer (score 2):

We use the classification of singularities: if f is bounded on $D^*(0,2)$ it cannot have a pole or an essential singularity, so it must be removable, and as such, we can create a new function $\widetilde{f}$ that agrees with f on $D^*(0,2)$ and is holomorphic on $D(0,2)$. Because the disk is homotopic to a point, $\widetilde{f}$ has integral $0$ over any closed curve, and so f does as well on any curve not containing the origin.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible this problem might be assigned without Riemann's removable singularity theorem a known result. The Cauchy theorem in a basic form could still show $$\int_{|z|=1}f(z)\,dz - \int_{|z|=r}f(z)\,dz =0.$$ Here $r>0$ is small. The second integral in absolute value is bounded by $M(2\pi r),$ so taking the limit as $r\to 0$ gives the result.

Comment: In fact the above is a way to prove Riemann's theorem. =)

Comment: So f is bounded by M and since Gamma is in D(0;2) wouldn't just proving the Cauchy Integral Formula be enough to show that the integral is 0? But how does that work with D being punctured?

Answer (score 2):

Define $g(z)=z f(z)$. Then $g$ is analytic in $0 < |z| <2$ and, by the given condition, $\lim_{z \to 0} g(z)=0$.  This shows that $g$ can be extended to an Analytic function on $|z| <2$.

Now, by Cauchy Integral formula
$$0=g(0) = \int_{|z|=1} \frac{g(z)}{z} dz = \int_{|z|=1} f(z) dz$$